# Link image in panel

Tags: wordpress, yoothemes

I have this panel made with yootheme builder. I would like the image to have the link as well as the button. https://www.diningsix.dk/panel-test/

I found this solution on another website but it doesn't seam to work:

```
    <script>
jQuery(function(){
jQuery('.linkpanel .uk-card > .uk-card-body > .readmore').each( function(){
var readmore = jQuery(this);
var href = jQuery(readmore).attr('href');
var link = '<a href="' + href + '"></a>';
jQuery(readmore).closest('.uk-card').find('.uk-card-media-top, .el-title, .el-content').wrap(link);
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try putting the image into anchor tag? like this: `<a href="http:\\example.com"> <img> </a>`

Answer (score 0):

This seams to work..

```
jQuery('body').ready(function(){
    jQuery('.uk-card').each(function(){
        $card = jQuery(this)
        var link = $card.find('.el-link').attr('href')
        if(link){
            $card.find('.el-image').wrap('<a href=' + link + '></a>')
        }
    })
})
```